# Web server won't allow more than 4 connections

Tags: iis, signalr

I am running WEB.API backend with Angular front end, using SignalR (2.2.0) with almost constant data changes.

My problem is that I am able to connect only 4 clients, 5th client would not connect. It will load all web page data, but SignalR won't connect. As soon as I disconnt 
one of the 4 already connected clients, the 5th one would connect with not problems.

This is running on Windows 8.1 with IIS 8.5 on separate LAN.

IIS settings is default. Where shall I start looking to solve this?

Thank you.

update: in addition to below link provide by @thab, here is another one with concurent connection limits in IIS per Windows version: http://jpelectron.com/sample/WWW%20and%20HTML/IIS-%20OS%20Version%20Limits.htm

Comment: Hi please check this link https://www.iis.net/configreference/system.applicationhost/sites/site/limits and find the usage of "maxConnections" using find. I think it should have set to 4. Hope it helps

Comment: Maximum Concurrent Connections is 4294967295 ...

Comment: Its not tested from the same client? You can only have 4 connections from the same client

Comment: @Anders what do you mean?

Comment: Chrome etc, can only have 4 tabs using web sockets to the same end point. It wont allow more

Comment: This is from different clients (with different IP). Not from one browser...

Comment: THen we sorted that out :D For the problem I was thinking of here is how you can solve that, https://github.com/slimjack/IWC-SignalR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's because you're using Windows 8.1 - there's a limit to the number of simultaneous connections that IIS supports on non-server versions of Windows:

http://weblogs.asp.net/owscott/windows-8-iis-8-concurrent-requests-limit

The problem relates to how SignalR holds a persistent connection (whether Forever Frames, Server Sent Events or Web Sockets) and if the limit is 10 connections, then you'll only be able to get a few users online at once...