# SignalR chat with multiple windows bomb out after a certain number of chat windows open

Tags: asp.net, iframe, telerik, signalr, radwindow

I've got SignalR running in an ASP.Net web app for a chat system.

I'm using the SQL scaleout.

The ASP.Net web app uses the telerik RadWindows to mimic an MDI interface.

The RadWindows opens up pages in an iframe; so each time a user starts a new chat,
a new iframe is used to open up another instance of my chat page.

Everything seems to be working fine if I have a small number chat windows.

In my dev environment, if I have more than 3 chats open, the 4th I try to open does not work.

In our production environment, they are only getting 2 chat windows to open and the 3rd does not work.

When the window that doesn't work opens, it locks up the entire web app.
So if I try to open another page (in the MDI-like interface), this new page will not load at all.  Soon as I close the locked up chat window, the new page loads.

This all leads me to believe it is related to number of connections or concurrency.  But I've had no luck all morning trying to figure out a fix or workaround.

Thanks!

Sam

Comment: Are you hitting a browser limit? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/985431/max-parallel-http-connections-in-a-browser

Comment: What version of Windows are you using in your environments? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34854939/web-server-wont-allow-more-than-4-connections/34855513#34855513 for a similar situation when Windows Server is not used